# 4 bit synchronous counter circuit that counts from 1 to 6

Tags: counter, ise

[image]

I'm having trouble answering this question, it is for my laboratory. My online lab sessions only discussed how to answer it briefly.

I am not sure how to go from here, I've filled in the K-map with ones and don't cares just so 1-6 numbers are valid but I am not sure how to make the schematic for this?

Comment: The "Paste optional Schematic from ISE " suggest this has to be done using the Xilinx HDL tools. Is this supposed to be written in verilog/VHDL?

Answer (score -3):

So you need to detect a 6, and on the next clock edge cause a preset to 0001.

Comment: This is a sketchy, undetailed comment but posted as an answer.